# input n as number then return '0' & '1' as number of n rows and columns in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

input n as number then return '0' & '1' as number of n rows and columns in python (without using any inbuilt type of function or library)

If input n = 3

```
The output: 

100
010
001
```

If input n = 4

```
The output:

1000
0100
0010
0001
```

I tried myself below, but i failed to achieve.

```
n = 3

for i in range(1, n+1):
    for j in range(i, n+1):
        if i == j:
            print(1)
        else:
            print(0)
        break
```

Anyone who can solve, will be much appreciated.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @matszwecja 

n = 3

for i in range(1, n+1):
    for j in range(i, n+1):
        if i == j:
            print(1)
        else:
            print(0)
        break

Comment: With respect to doing your homework, ["Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/2081835)

Comment: @satyajit good, now edit that into your question, and tell us how it failed to do what you wanted it to.

Comment: this is not a homework, this is the  part of problem that i was trying to solve. @theherk

Comment: If it's not homework, what prevents you using functions or libraries?

Comment: No reason to be dishonest if it is homework, but whether it is or not is sort of irrelevant. If you need other references on making an attempt yourself first, see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example that forms each line into a string and then prints it to the console:

```
n = 3
for i in range(n): 
    line = ""
    for j in range(n):
        if i == j:
            line += "1"
        else:
            line += "0"
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy?

```
import numpy as np
n = 3
result = np.identity(n)
```

Comment: using core python only. no module or library.

Comment: Please put this into your initial questions. It might help others to not propose something like this.

Comment: ok. can you solve this using core python?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use binary representations of powers of 2:

```
def out(n):
    return "\n".join(f"{1<<i:0{n}b}" for i in range(n-1,-1,-1))

print(out(4))
```

Comment: That's certainly one way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way: start by forming the matrix as a line and then print out the n-by-n matrix.

```
def identity(n):
    out = (n*"0").join(n*["1"])
    for i in range(n):
        print(out[i*n:][:n])
```